# rpm post install commands not executing

Tags: maven, rpm

I created a rpm file using the maven rpm plugin(2.1-alpha-1). I need to execute two commands in the %post of the rpm file. The generated spec file and the command "rpm -q --scripts filename" show both the commands. 
Here is the output of "rpm -q --scripts filename | less "

```
postinstall scriplet (using /bin/sh):
ln -s /etc/init.d/source /etc/init.d/target
ln -s /var/app/source1 /var/app/target1
```

Here is how the commands are given in the rpm plugin section

```
    <postinstall>ln -s /etc/init.d/source /etc/init.d/target 
    ln -s /var/app/source1 /var/app/target1</postinstall>
    <!-- I have tried to separate the two commands with ";" 
too but that does not work either.-->
```

However only the second one gets executed. Anything I am missing here??  Any workarounds to get this done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm... are we sure the second ln isn't executed? or is it failing to create the link?

Comment: The second ln gets executed and creates the link but the first one does not

Comment: BTW, your example is incorrect: `ln` arguments is wrong because as first parameter should be specified target, not source file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not a packaging problem.  Instead SELinux might be enabled on you target system, and it might be blocking the creation of the link, so check /var/log/audit/audit.log to see if any deny messages are being generated.

You might also want to manually try the 'ln -s /etc/init.d/source /etc/init.d/target' as root on the target system.  If SELinux is biting you, this would also fail.